# More than 2 precision rounding with formatted using Monetary API java

Tags: java, currency, currency-formatting

I am using Monetary API to format Money value in java. It is giving wrong value with more than 2 rounding when I format value using `MonetaryAmountFormat`. Let say example:

```
  private static final MonetaryAmountFormat MONETARY_AMOUNT_FORMAT = MonetaryFormats.getAmountFormat(Locale.getDefault());
    MonetaryAmount amount = Monetary.getDefaultAmountFactory()
            .setCurrency(currencyUnit).setNumber(Double.valueOf(value.toString())).create().with(rounding);
    value = MONETARY_AMOUNT_FORMAT.format(amount);
```

Output of above example:

```
Rounding = 2, amount = 12323.45, value =12,323.45 //OK
Rounding = 3, amount = 12323.45334, value =12,323.45 //Wrong, it should convert it 12323.453
```

is there any way to achieve more than 2 rounding with formatting?

Comment: Your using Locale.getDefault() which tied to your local settings. Try create your own custom format.

Comment: Look at the examples here: http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=javax.money.format.MonetaryFormats. You can change the `pattern`

Comment: yes I see. I have rounding as Integer value only. I don't want apply pattern. As per  impl, I have only rounding which coming from configuration like 2,3, etc any integer number. I want to use default local pattern. only precision change required,

Answer (score 1):

You can change the number of decimal place by changing the pattern:

```
@Test
public void formatMoneyCustom2() throws Exception {
    final MonetaryAmountFormat format = MonetaryFormats.getAmountFormat(
            AmountFormatQueryBuilder.of(Locale.US)
                    .set(CurrencyStyle.SYMBOL)
                    .set("pattern", "#,##0.00### ¤")
                    .build()
    );
    final String formatted = format.format(MoneyImpl.ofCents(123456, "USD"));
    assertThat(formatted).isEqualTo("1,234.56 $");
}
```

Comment: +1 Thanks. It wan't work in my case as I have only scale value. There should be default format need to use everytime. Only precision part taken care. is there any other way, also let me try as per your customized one

Comment: Since the default format, format to 2.d.p, it overrides your rounding. As the example above, specify many decimal places in the format then you can still apply the rounding afterward.

Comment: you mean create pattern manually based on rounding. it seems not good approach.  is there any otherway

Comment: I meant specify the `pattern` to have upto 10 d.p. and then apply your rounding to whichever d.p you needed. e.g. `.set("pattern", "#,##0.00000000000### ¤")`

Answer (score 0):

For those looking to achieve 2 or more precision rounding:

```
CurrencyUnit euro = Monetary.getCurrency("EUR");
MonetaryAmount monetaryAmount = Monetary.getDefaultAmountFactory().setCurrency(euro).setNumber( 12323.4556 ).create();
monetaryAmount = monetaryAmount.with(Monetary.getRounding(RoundingQueryBuilder.of().set(RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN).setScale(2).build()));
System.out.prinln(monetaryAmount.getNumber());  // 12323.46
monetaryAmount = monetaryAmount.with(Monetary.getRounding(RoundingQueryBuilder.of().set(RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN).setScale(3).build()));
System.out.prinln(monetaryAmount.getNumber());  // 12323.456
```